# BRKINT is not working

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, break, termios

BRKINT is not working

```
struct termios     term;
  uint8_t stop_bits = 0;
  memset(&term, 0, sizeof(struct termios));
  fd = open(device_name, O_RDWR);
  if(fd == -1)
  {
    LOGI("Could not open serial device file, errno : %d ", errno, 0, 0);
  }
  /* Change the mode to TTY. */
  LOGI("Successfully opened UART device file. FD is %d", uart_serial_fd);
  if (tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH) < 0)
  {
    LOGI("issue while tcflush ");
    close(fd);
  }
  if (tcgetattr(fd, &term) < 0) {
      LOGI("issue while tcgetattr ");
      close(fd);
  }
  cfmakeraw(&term);
  /* Set RTS/CTS HW Flow Control*/
  term.c_cflag |= (CRTSCTS | stop_bits);
  term.c_iflag |= BRKINT;
  if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &term) < 0) {
     LOGI("issue while tcsetattr ");
     close(fd);
  }
```

I have registered with the signal as:
signal(SIGINT, sig_int_handler);

```
void sig_int_handler(int sig)
{
  LOGI("\n received break - sig int \n");
  LOG_MSG_INFO1("\n received break - sig int \n",0,0,0);
}
```

But still I am not getting signal when break is detected or when <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> is pressed.

Comment: Don't use [signal()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) (see section "Portability"), use [sigaction()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) instead.

Comment: And then, the second problem might be that your `LOGI()` and `LOG_MSG_INFO1()` do things that are not [signal safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). Best practice is to keep signal handlers as short as possible, maybe just setting a `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable, and do the work in the main code.

Comment: I will take care of signal handling thing as you all mentioned. But i wanted to confirm setting struct termios is correct or i am going wrong?

Comment: I have no experience with that, but as your code does incorrect things with signals, it's best to fix that first, so you will see whether it works. You could maybe test your signal handling by explicitly sending signals or using something like `alarm()`

Comment: Here's a [super simple example](https://ideone.com/61n57h) -- in real life code, you'll probably have some main loop -- just check the signal flag in every iteration and/or after every interruptible syscall.

Comment: regarding: `term.c_iflag |= BRKINT;`  Per the man page: " BRKINT If  IGNBRK  is  set,  a  BREAK is ignored.  If it is not set but
              BRKINT is set, then a BREAK causes the input and  output  queues
              to  be  flushed, and if the terminal is the controlling terminal
              of a foreground process group, it will cause a SIGINT to be sent
              to  this  foreground  process  group."  so the bit: `IGNBRK ` must also be cleared to 0

Comment: cfmakeraw(&term); will clear the IGNBRK flag according to man page